# improving resolution of jpeg images in matlab

Tags: matlab, pdf, figure

I have a jpeg which has reasonable resolution. I am looking for a method of improving the resolution of the image and then exporting it into a pdf file.

Currently I have imported the jpeg:

```
Img = imread('F:Work\fig.jpg');
```

From here I was hoping of exporting the figure by using the export_fig function:

https://sites.google.com/site/oliverwoodford/software/export_fig

But I am struggling on generating the figure which is required prior to exporting the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What part of the figure creation process are you struggling with?  The general approach I would use is

```
Img = imread('F:Work\fig.jpg');
bigImg = imresize(Img,2);
imshow(bigImg);
export_fig test.png -native;
```

Check Matlab's documentation for different interpolation options that can be used when [resizing images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html).

Comment: I receive an error: Undefined function 'imresize' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Comment: Image resize is part of the image processing toolbox, you probably don't have it.  I found a free copy on the mathworks file exchange [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30787-image-resize) but I've never used it so can't be certain it works.  Do you have access to the image processing toolbox on another pc?

Comment: I would save the image using imwrite rather than export_fig here.